# Append Native Event Handler to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events, react-dom

In my app, I wish to not use React's own event system. [As per the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#overview):

> If you find that you need the underlying browser event for some reason, simply use the nativeEvent attribute to get it.

However, the following doesn't work and returns an error.

```
// onclick is DOM native event-handler; React's alternative is onClick
<div id = "main" onclick = {( e ) => this.onclickHandler( e )}...
// console error: Unknown event handler property onclick...
```

Edit:

I understand I can do something along the lines of the following, however, I wonder why the above wouldn't work. Is the following way of binding the handler via `addEventListener` the only way?

```
componentDidMount(){
  window.addEventListener("click", this.handleblahblah);
  ...
}
handleblahblah(){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it, I have come to realise my mistake. In case someone else wonders about this, here is the reason this above binding of `onclick` doesnt work.

`React Components are not the same as DOM elements.`

In the above code, we are delegating binding of methods over to React. React doesn't recognise `onclick`, which is a DOM keyword for handling `click` events.

An alternative to above solution (using addEventListener) could be to access the element via React's `refs` method. `refs` gives you access to the underlying DOM element. Then bind `onclick` method.

```
class exampleComponent extends Component{
...
componentDidMount(){
  this.mainInterface.onclick = (e) => this.onclickEventHandler(e);
}
render(){
...
  <div id = "main" refs = {( main ) => this.mainInterface = main }
  ...
```